# Proof for the Rule of Absorption in Natural Deduction?

Tags: logic, deduction, symbolic-logic

I know there is a "formal proof" in "natural deduction" for the "rule of absorption" that employs the "law of excluded middle".  It is presented in Wikipedia (and I think it is Russell's): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(logic)#Formal_proof.

It is also obvious how the proof could be done by way of a "conditional" or "indirect" proof.

However, is there a "formal proof" in "natural deduction" for the "rule of absorption" that does NOT assert the "law of excluded middle (or non-contradiction)" *as a rule of inference* or employ a "conditional (or indirect) proof"?

That is to say, can a proof in "natural deduction" be constructed that goes from the premise **p⊃q** to the conclusion **p⊃(p∙q)** WITHOUT using the "law of excluded middle (LEM)" as a *rule of inference* or employing a "conditional proof (CP)" or "indirect proof (IP)"?

Comment: Out of curiosity and considering you're not accepting the answer using a truth table, how do you define the truth-functional operation of a conditional for the purposes of your question? (normally one does so with a truth table)

Comment: It is not that I am not accepting the answer.  Of course, a truth table shows us not only that going from p⊃q to p⊃(p∙q) is valid but moreover that p⊃q and p⊃(p∙q) are equivalent statements (which makes Copi's applying absorption as a rule of implication curious, but I digress).  Bottom line, I am just wanting to know about its proof in so-called natural deduction, and whether or not it can be done without CP or LEM (it seems that it cannot be, which is revelatory regarding absorption's applicability in philosophical logic).  That is all!

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my above comment. I'll try to re-express it. (1) the function p⊃q is normally defined by a truth table  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional).  As in, p⊃q is precisely the function that produces the output the truth table dictates. (2) answer below uses truth table to derive p⊃(p∙q). (3) you object to answer since truth table presupposes bivalence and/or LEM. (4) Wouldn't it follow that your objection also applies to definition of p⊃q  ?

Comment: Put another way, if (3) is a problem, then isn't (1) a problem too? And if (1) isn't a problem, then (3) doesn't seem to be one either.... So it seems you should either give a definition of p⊃q  that is not a truth table or accept the validity of the proof via truth-table.

Comment: Ugh...  I accept the validity of the proof via a truth table.  When did I say I did not?  Heck, I have written in comments things like "Knowing it is valid ..."  SO, _knowing that it is valid_, I just want to know if a proof in natural deduction can be done for it without using CP or LEM.  It seems that it cannot.

Comment: That is to say, I just want to know if a proof in natural deduction can be done for it without using CP or _explicitly_ using LEM, _that is, as a rule of inference within the system_, unlike the one here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(logic), which I think originally is Russell's.  Again, it seems that it cannot.

Comment: I can tell you must be frustrated but I think my point is simpler (and / or on a different level?) than what you're responding to... To state clearly, **I agree that it may be impossible to accomplish such a proof without CP, LEM, or truth tables.** Where I'm lost is how you can define ⊃ without giving it the standard truth table we expect.

Comment: and then once we've done that, haven't we committed ourselves to accepting the truth table proof (at a minimum)? I'm trying to think of a good analogy, but nothing immediately comes to mind.  Best thing I've got so far, if we accept that I can only communicate in French and you understand what I'm saying, it follows that we're communicating in French.

Comment: Hi, virmaior...  I gotchya!  Let me cut to the chase here...  Is your bottom-line query (and qualm) just really, "What is your point, Stegdude?  A truth table demonstrates absorption's validity (and, indeed, equivalence).  Let's set aside LEM as a rule within the system as many do not allow that, such as the constructivists.  CP, however, is totally logical and allowable in like every system of propositional logic on Earth.  So, why would you care whether or not a proof in natural deduction can be constructed for absorption _without_ CP?"  Am I getting you right, virmaior? :)

Comment: No. That's not it at all.

Comment: My bottom line point is: can you define ⊃  without using a truth table (or essentially the same thing)?  If so, then I'd love to hear how. If not, then I don't see how we can reject truth tables for proving absorption.

Comment: In all honesty, I do not even know what the question, "can you define ⊃ without using a truth table (or essentially the same thing)?" means.  So, my de facto answer is "No."  That said, for the umpteenth time, I do not reject the proof of absorption by truth table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(logic)#Proof_by_truth_table).  I just want the "formal proof" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(logic)#Formal_proof), BUT without using LEM (as that one does) or CP.  Can it be done?  If so, lay it on me.  That is all I am asking for.  I am under the impression that it cannot be.

Comment: I'm really lost as to where you're not following me at this point. The definition of ⊃ in the truth-table seems to use LEM or at least bivalency. And the proof of absorption by truth table is no different on that point. If ⊃ is formally defined by its truth table, then absorption is formally proved by the same sort of truth table. If the definition is legitimate, there's no further moves in the truth table proof...

Comment: Per the links I provided (as examples)...  I do not want the "truth-table proof".  I am talking about the "formal proof".  That distinction is registering for you, right?  Assuming so, is your point, then, that because the "proof by truth table" for absorption uses LEM, the "formal proof" for absorption must, as well???

Comment: (1) I'm not grasping why the truth-table proof does not qualify as a formal proof. Sure, the methods are different than what you'er calling a "formal proof" but the theory is sound. (2) `Assuming so, is your point, then, that because the "proof by truth table" for absorption uses LEM ...`  **NO**. My point is that the definition of ⊃ itself assumes LEM before you can get to proving anything whether that proof is by truth table or some other method. / Restated, the thing you seem to want to avoid appears to be baked into the very nature of ⊃ and I don't know how you can unbake it.

Comment: First off, I edited my question for clarity's sake. :)  ...  Yes, you are exactly right, virmaior!  The key word there is "assume", a word I have been going to great lengths to avoid using.  LEM is _assumed_ in both proof methods.  If it is "assumed", baked in the cake, then it should not have to be _asserted_ as an explicit rule of inference to prove anything within the system.  Indeed, almost no contemporary "formal proof" system (influenced by constructivism?) employs LEM as a rule of inference.  So, why do we suddenly need to _assert_ it to provide a "formal proof" for absorption?  ...

Comment: ...  Well, the truth is that we do NOT have to _assert_ LEM.  It can remain _assumed_, and we can instead do a "formal proof" for absorption by using CP (or IP, which, of course, is just a kind of CP).  But, there are problems with doing it with CP, too! :(

Comment: Talk about a LATE reply, virmaior!  LOL!  First off, I apologize for the poor wording of my originally edited query.  I thought it was obvious that I was asking for the proof in "natural deduction".  That was projection on my part.  In hindsight, all of my uses of the broad phrases "formal proof" and "propositional logic" (without clearly specifying in no uncertain terms the form of the proof method I wanted used) were not helpful and, indeed, only made what I was asking unclear.  ANYway, I have, alas, edited it accordingly! :)

Comment: Explore *logical relations*. Your resources may be better expended there. I could be wrong though i.e. it's just a hunch.

Comment: Thanks!  I will give it a look.  With that said, it has been over six years since I posted this and betwixt, I have done A LOT of research and rigorous logicking things out on this and related points/theorems, and the answer, indeed, is, as the trajectory of the answers and comments here suggests, "no".  I just happened to stumble back upon this old page a couple nights ago and thought that, despite the answer's being "no" and all the time that has passed, the original question and post should be cleaned up. :)

Comment: I should qualify my last comment with: the answer to the question is "no,... not according to your run-of-the-mill, twentieth-century (eighteen-or-so rule) systems of natural deduction and, no, not that is publicly known... _yet_." ;)

Answer (score 4):

The *rule of absorption* can be proved via truth table (which is neither a "conditional proof" nor an "indirect proof") like so:

```
P Q | P ⊃ Q | (P ∙ Q) | P ⊃ (P ∙ Q) | (P ⊃ Q) ≡ [P ⊃ (P ∙ Q)]
-----------------------------------------------------------
0 0 |   1   |    0    |   1         |         1
0 1 |   1   |    0    |   1         |         1
1 0 |   0   |    0    |   0         |         1
1 1 |   1   |    1    |   1         |         1
```

But, if truth tables presuppose the law of excluded middle, then it would seem that the *rule of absorption* is *not* provable within the constraints you've imposed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jayson!  I am, however, not looking just to prove/demonstrate that the "rule of absorption" is valid.  Knowing it is valid, I am looking for a "formal proof", a formal deduction, (so-called) natural deduction or otherwise, for the "rule of absorption".  That said, you did directly answer my question with your last sentence... in (per what I had written in my message before it got edited out) the "straightforward" way I have come to anticipate (having messed with this for quite some time), that is, "NO!"  Do you really think that is the bottom line?

Comment: Jayson, also, one other thought...  Is it that truth tables presuppose the "law of excluded middle" or the "principle of bivalence"?  If the latter, then your answer was more on point than you or I were giving it credit for being.  That said, I am ultimately looking for the "formal deductive proof", which we both seem to believe does not exist. XD

Comment: The idea that the truth value of P, and the truth value of Q have to be either 0 or 1 *is* the LEM, right?  If you want not to presume the LEM, you would have to include options for where either one was still undecided.  You would also need a standard of implication that does not automatically assume that the implication always has a truth value.

Comment: @Stegfucius I'd say they presuppose bivalence, but that bivalence as a property of the semantics relies on LEM in the meta language used to state the semantics. At the very least, the intuition regarding truth being an "on" or "off" property of propositions seems to be what motivates both LEM and bivalence. If the semantic values of propositions aren't regarded as truth values, it's hard to see why you'd insist there are only two. For instance, consider an intuitionist who replaces "truth" with "proof", or the construction of Boolean valued models beyond the two element Boolean algebra.

Comment: Well, truth table is powerful tool. At least for binary logic.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer because it uses conditional elimination and conditional introduction which may be prohibited.  However, it does not use the law of excluded middle (LEM).

As I understand the comments there is some question about the prohibition of rules for conditionals if one allows a conditional in the premise and a conditional in the conclusion. If one uses conditionals to state the proof, rules for manipulating the conditional should be specified.

The proof was made using Kevin Klement's [natural deduction proof editor and checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/).

[image]

Here is [the proof of absorption using LEM in the cited Wikipedia article, "Absorption (logic)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(logic)#Formal_proof):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I claim that there is no such proof, ie no such proof of A:= (p -> q) \implies [p -> (p \land q)] that does not use, as stated in OP, *conditional proof*, *indirect proof*, or *LEM*.

*I will now use derivation to denote proofs in object language*

We will work in intuitionisitc sequent calculus, without R->, since this rule corresponds to conditional proof, and intuitionistic calculus, since this rules out indirect or LEM. Suppose there exist such a derivation, that is a derivation of A. By cut elimination, there exists a derivation without cut. Now, by direct inspection of the (non structural) rules, we see that there is no way to introduce -> on the right. The only rule we can use is L->, from which we obtain \implies p, and our proof search thus terminates immediately.

The same idea works for ND, just via normalization instead of cut, and ->I instead of R->. Note that absorption is provable intuitionisitically, so its key that you disallow conditional proof for this to be the case.

How does this work in a Hilbert Style logic? Since we allow axioms K, S, we obtain a proof of deduction theorem, which is equivalent to allowing conditional proof. So if you don't want to allow conditional proof you must disallow those as well. In particular, in this case, you must disallow S.

Comment: I don’t see how using axioms that validate the *admissibility* of the Deduction Theorem counts as using it; after all, cut-free proofs don’t somehow lose that aspect once cut’s admissibility is proven.

Comment: @PW_246 its a good point. in practice, conditional inference has not been employed. In principle, K, S are chosen for an easy proof of deduction, allowing us to do everything that conditional inference is "supposed to do". So we choose axioms and rules that allow us to derive the rule we say we don't want to use,  and then when we use them, we say we haven't.

Comment: in classical logic, connectives are interdefinable. So suppose I prove something using only &, ~, v, but not ->. Have I avoided conditional proof? Maybe.

Comment: conditional proof (if you buy something along the line of Witt, Dummett) is intimately related to meaning of conditonal, whereas its not clear to me that structural rules bear the same relation to meaning. But I don't pretend that these are water tight arguments, only considerations in a fairly deep matter

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a Hilbert-Style proof using the axiom scheme from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system

1. P→(Q→(P&Q))                       (&-Intro)
2. (P→(Q→(P&Q)))→((P→Q)→(P→(P&Q)))  (P3)
3. (P→Q)→(P→(P&Q))  (1,2 MP)

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks, PW_246!  I was looking for the proof to be done in natural deduction, though.  I could be wrong, but I think the reason it can be done in axiomatic systems of propositional logic, such as Hilbert systems, is that the law of excluded middle/formal tautologicality is built into the system via the axioms/rules.  Indeed, that would be the case for both &-Intro and P3 there, right?

Comment: No, this proof does not require the law of the excluded middle. In general, if a proof doesn’t need DNE in natural deduction, it doesn’t need LEM or something equivalent in the usual Hilbert axiomatic system.

Comment: I understand...  I am saying that axiomatic systems of logic incorporate formal tautologicality via their axioms/rules (and, therefore, _imply_ the law of excluded middle).  After all, both &-Intro and P3 are tautologies, a.k.a. necessary truths.

Comment: The axioms I used are not sufficient to prove LEM by themselves.

Comment: Of course, they cannot, but, with all due respect, I did not say that "the axioms you used are sufficient to prove ...," I said that "axiomatic systems _imply_ ..."  But, **_ANYway_**, &-Intro and P3 are tautologies (which is enough to make my point, _as I see it_, but I digress).

Comment: I’m honestly confused here, but for Classical Propositional Logic, if an axiom set isn’t enough to prove a theorem, that theorem can’t be built into it.

Comment: Roger!  Tautologicality is a feature, not a theorem.  But, yes, I am thinking outside the box here, which I think logic needs more of.  The field is a mess... and stagnant.  Fewer and fewer people are interested in logic because it has become so abstruse, almost to the point of esoteric.  Yet, we live in increasingly illogical times, and logic is a tool for the people.  Back to the field, everybody is stuck in boxes.  We keep producing books and materials that all re-present the same s**t or is unreadable.  Thanks for taking a peek at this, in any case.  Your axiomatic proof is helpful. :)